# Using the same control to return JSON/XML/HTML with Web API MVC4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am guessing it has been asked before but I did not see it and thought maybe I am missing something fundamental.  My question is why can't I have one API controller that bases the format of result on the accepted content format(i.e. application/json)?  Maybe I am being lazy - but I rather do something like if html is the expected result format than let me return a view, if json is the accept format than I can return JSOn -etc...  If I have two namespaces, then that is also two methods I have to maintain - when the only difference is the media format.

Answer (score 0):

When you return an object from an action in a web api controller, what is actually going on behind the scenes looks like this:

```
 public class SessionController : ApiController
    {

        public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
        {
            var vm = new SessionDetailViewModel {Speaker = "Bob", Title = "Bob's talk"};

            var conneg = new DefaultContentNegotiator();
            var result = conneg.Negotiate(typeof (SessionDetailViewModel), this.Request,Configuration.Formatters);
            var content = new ObjectContent<SessionDetailViewModel>(vm, result.Formatter,result.MediaType);

            return new HttpResponseMessage() {Content = content};
        }
    }
```

As long as you have the appropriate set of formatters that can map the returned object to the wire format then conneg will happen automatically.

Comment: Also: JSON and XML are supported out of the box. There is no built-in HTML formatter, but I know that people have written some.

Comment: I guess I am also asking - why should there be two separate controllers? Just like how it delivers XML/json based on the accept format in the request - couldn't do the same for html?

Comment: @ecco88  You can do it with just one controller.  I've played around with the idea a bit.  I have an example here that returns html, plain text and OData from the same controller https://github.com/darrelmiller/HypermediaApiSite/blob/master/HypermediaApiSiteConsole/Root/Learning/LearningController.cs